# C++ - Strangely formatted hexadecimal output

Tags: c++

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I'm trying to output the hexadecimal value of each byte in a file (*.bmp in this case). I have successfully loaded the file in memory, and am able to print hex values of bytes. but when I print certain bytes,When I print certain bytes, for example the 3rd byte (at offset 2), it prints FFFFFFE6, but my hexdump(using HxD) of the file says it is just E6. This happens only on certain bytes, the others print just fine.

Main.cpp is:

```
#include "main.h"

int main () 
{
    ifstream::pos_type size;
    char * memblock;

    ifstream file ("C:\\hex.bmp", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);

    size = file.tellg();

    memblock = new char [size];

    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file.read(memblock, size);
    file.close();
    printf("%X", memblock[2]);

    delete[] memblock;

    cin.get();
}
```

Main.h is:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#endif
```

Comment: Try making memblock an `unsigned char *`.

Comment: @Deanie I (and [other people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325790/3266847)) see that you're doing a lot of edits where you clean up C/C++ tags. This is, by itself, a good thing, but if you do an edit, make sure it counts, i.e., improve everything there is to improve and don't just remove a single tag. This post has a tag in its title [where it arguably doesn't belong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), and there are a few typos in the first paragraph, which you should have fixed as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand how variable arguments and [standard integral conversions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n) work. When you `char` is signed, you're in trouble.

Always print bytes as *unsigned* chars:

```
char data[100];

printf("%02X", (unsigned char)data[i]);
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```